# H2o Grid-Search for Quantile Regression/Prediction Interval

Tags: python, regression, intervals, h2o, quantile

I am currently working on calculation of prediction intervals derived through quantile regression with H2o DeepLearning and GradientBoosting. In H2o you have to build and train separate Models for each interval, e.g.:

For the 95% Prediction Interval you would need a separate model for the lower bound `(100-95)/2)=2.5%` and the upper bound `(100 - (100-95)/2)=97.5%`. 
Now, I am trying to optimise model-parameter through Grid-Search. What would be the best approach?

Running Grid-Search for one of the models and using the parameters of the best model of the grid for all models.

Or running a separate grid for each model and getting two models with different parameters in the end?

My concern is, that in option two the whole interval will be not consistent, as the two models are not comparable anymore.

Has anyone experience with this?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by the two models are not comparable anymore and the interval is not consisten? for option two do you want to compare how your two models (which were trained on different quantiles) perform on the entire interval?

Comment: that was just an assumption. as I am getting an interval, derived from the outputs of two distinct models, one would suggest that the two models should have any connection (e.g. the same set of parameters). In option two, I will have two completely different models(trained on the same data though). Does that still make sense to combine the outputs in order to derive an interval?